# How to call both javascript and php complete in editing html file with vim?

Tags: autocompletion

I have installed tern_for_vim and setted complete in .vimrc.

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

Now i can call javascript  complete  when editing html file via ctrl+x and ctrl+o.
The php completion can pop up when editing a php file (vim test.php) via ctrl+x and ctrl+o.
Many php and javascript code snippets are embeded in a html file.

What i can do now:
During editing my html file(vim test.html), when javascript complete needed ,it can call via ctrl+x and ctrl+o;  when php complete needed ,it can't call via ctrl+x and ctrl+o.

What i expect:
During editing my html file(vim test.html), when javascript complete needed ,it can call via ctrl+x and ctrl+o;  when php complete needed ,it can  call via ctrl+x and ctrl+o.
YouCompleteMe and tern_for_vim  installed.

```
cat  .tern-project
{
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "libs": [
        "browser",
        "underscore",
        "jquery"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "node": {}
    }
}
```

I reset my .vimrc according to Rich's code.

```
cat .vimrc
set nobackup
set nowritebackup    
set tabstop=4
set sts=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4    
set number    
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin on    
autocmd FileType html setlocal omnifunc=MyHTMLComplete
function! MyHTMLComplete(findstart, base)
    if search('<?php', 'bnW') > search('<script>', 'bnW')
        return phpcomplete#CompletePHP(a:findstart, a:base)
    else
        return tern#Complete(a:findstart,a:base)
    endif
endfunction

ls .vim/bundle
phpcomplete.vim  tabular  tern_for_vim  webapi-vim  YouCompleteMe


vim test.html
<script>
    document.get 
</script>
```

[image: js complete in html file called by ctrl-x + ctrl-o]

Add php code snippet to test complete.

[image: php complete in html file can't called by ctrl-x + ctrl-o]

Edit a single test.php file.
[image: php complete in php file called by ctrl-x + ctrl-o]

How to achieve my target?

Setting .vimrc as setting1 :

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin on    
autocmd FileType html setlocal omnifunc=MyHTMLComplete
function! MyHTMLComplete(findstart, base)
    if search('<?php', 'bnW') > search('<script>', 'bnW')
        return phpcomplete#CompletePHP(a:findstart, a:base)
    else
        return tern#Complete(a:findstart,a:base)
    endif
endfunction
```

Setting .vimrc as setting2 :

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
filetype plugin on    
autocmd FileType html setlocal omnifunc=MyHTMLComplete
function! MyHTMLComplete(findstart, base)
    if search('<?php', 'bnW') > search('<script>', 'bnW')
        return phpcomplete#CompletePHP(a:findstart, a:base)
    else
        return tern#Complete(a:findstart,a:base)
    endif
endfunction
```

It is tested that both setting1 and setting2 take the same effect.

```
verbose :set omnifunc?
  omnifunc=MyHTMLComplete
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: What happens if you add the line `throw "PHP"` before the line `return phpcomplete...`?

Comment: Also, what is the result of `verbose :set omnifunc?` when run in an HTML file?

Comment: Your new pasted vimrc doesn't seem to include the lines you said you were using to set up completion. Are these actually set up by the plugins themselves?

Comment: You sort of addressed my third question, but not the first two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some rough code to start you off. Create the file `.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` and add the
following code:

```
setlocal omnifunc=MyHTMLComplete 

function! MyHTMLComplete(findstart, base)
    if search('<?php', 'bnW') > search('<script>', 'bnW')
        return phpcomplete#CompletePHP(a:findstart, a:base)
    else
        return tern#Complete(a:findstart,a:base)
    endif
endfunction
```

It first uses the `search()` function to look for the nearest `php` and `script` section starts, passing the following flags:

- `b` - search backwards,
- `n` - don't move the cursor,
- `W` - don't wrap around at the start of the file,

It then passes on the call to the corresponding existing complete function, depending on which section starts later.

This is obviously an exceedingly imprecise check of the current context. Hopefully this is enough to start you off, but you'll need to improve this quite a lot for this to be a robust solution!

Possibly a better technique for discerning what type of code you are in would be to use `synstack()` and its related functions to interrogate Vim's syntax highlighting information. Something like the following might work:

```
for id in synstack(line('.'), col('.'))
    if synIDattr(id, 'name') =~? 'javascript'
        echom "In Javascript!"
        break
    endif
endfor
```

For more details, see:

- `:help complete-functions`
- `:help search()`
- `:help synstack()`

Answer (score 0):

It works as following.

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType html setlocal omnifunc=MyHTMLComplete
function! MyHTMLComplete(findstart, base)
    autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete
    autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
    if search('<?php', 'bnW') > search('<script>', 'bnW')
        return phpcomplete#CompletePHP(a:findstart, a:base)
    else
        return tern#Complete(a:findstart,a:base)
    endif
endfunction
```